# Wayland autorotation doesnt work only x11 on 23.10

Tags: gnome, xorg, gnome-shell, wayland, 23.10

On ubuntu 23.10 autorotation works on x11.org but not on wayland. i dont know if in the future x11 will not be avaiable, so if wayland will be the only choice and if autorotation is not fix , people also me will not have this property enable in their devices.

is there a way to fix this issue, so that wayland do the autorotation correctly as x11, and i mean an updade will be avaiable to everyone to fix wayland ?

And on x11 on the rigth menu the autorotation bottom appear but not on wayland, on the gnome menu.

is canonical aware of this? and will be a update to fix this?

even with the recent updates doesnt work

Comment: Try the command `sudo apt install iio-sensors-proxy`, reboot. Then check if autorotation works on wayland

Comment: it said it couldnt find the package. however also in 23.04 autorotation didnt worked in wayland i was hoping it was fix in 23.10. and i think also in 22.04 also domt work.

Comment: Sorry, try `sudo apt install iio-sensor-proxy`

Comment: In any case, X11 is not completely going away anytime very soon. Most likely, x11 will still be there till the end of the life of the laptop